# How to check for nested object value in a dynamic way using key variables?

Tags: javascript

If I want to check for a specific (nested) object value, I can do this by

```
if (configuration?.my_project?.frontend?.version)
```

instead of

```
if (
    configuration && 
    configuration.my_project && 
    configuration.my_project.frontend && 
    configuration.my_project.frontend.version
)
```

But how do I handle this if I want to do this for dynamic keys using variables?

```
configuration[project][app].version
```

would fail for `{ my_project: {} }` as there is no `frontend`.

So if I want to check if `version` is missing for a specific app in a specific project, I'm going this way:

```
if (
    configuration &&
    configuration[project] &&
    configuration[project][app] &&
    !configuration[project][app].version
)
```

The only part I see is just `!configuration[project][app]?.version`, but this would also fail for `{ my_project: {} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
configuration?.[project]?.[app]?.version
```

But if you want to check *specifically* that `version` is missing (i.e. falsey) you'll need to split your tests:

```
const my_app = configuration?.[project]?.[app];
if (my_app && !my_app.version) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh. Didn't know, that I can put an `.`in between... And the second thing is exactlyy, what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional chaining for the brackets syntax like so:

```js
const configuration = {}
const project = 'someProject'
const app = 'someApp'

console.log(configuration?.[project]?.[app]?.version)
configuration[project] = {}
console.log(configuration?.[project]?.[app]?.version)
configuration[project][app] = {version: '1.0.0'}
console.log(configuration?.[project]?.[app]?.version)
```

More details in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining